# How to count text between two quotes?

Tags: c#

So simply:
all i want is:

**Input**: Hey "There i was missing you" "Once again"

**Output**: 2

**Inpu**t: Hey "There i was missing you" "Once again" "Just kidding"

**Output**: 3

Counting spaces never worked with me because: There are spaces in the text between quotes

Code i tested but never worked because of the reason above...

```
static int CountWords(string text)
{
    int wordCount = 0, index = 0;

    while (index < text.Length)
    {

        while (index < text.Length && !char.IsWhiteSpace(text[index]))
            index++;

        wordCount++;

        while (index < text.Length && char.IsWhiteSpace(text[index]))
            index++;
    }
    return wordCount;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions would work wonderfully here:

```
var count = Regex.Matches(input, "\".*?\"").Count;
```

Alternatively, other suggestions of counting the number of quotation marks and dividing by two would work just as well:

```
var count = input.Count(c => c == '"') / 2;
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y2zJTM) of it in action

Answer (score 0):

You could count the quotes and divide by 2.

```
int counter = 0;
int answer = 0;

foreach (char c in input)
{
    if(c == "\"")
    {
        counter++;
    }
}

answer = counter / 2;
```